# Laravel 5 allow login to only specific users based on user type

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.3

I have a users table which consists of multiple users and have successfully created authentication system using middleware. Now i would like to know is there any possibility to allow only specific users to log in and prevent other from logging-in based on their type( i.e i have already defined user_type column in my users table)

Comment: Yes it's possible to do that. If you would like more specific answer please provide details on what you want and what you already have.

Comment: If I remember correctly, and if not you can easily make them yourself laravel 5 comes with a postLogin and afterLogin function inside the Auth/LoginController, in these 2 functions you can execute your own custom checks to validate the user is allowed to login.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom fields in `Auth::attempt`:

```
class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Handle an authentication attempt.
     *
     * @return Response
     */
    public function authenticate()
    {
        if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password, 'user_type'=>10])) { //<---
            // Authentication passed...
        }
    }
}
```

Another solution is to log user in, then check which permission he/she has, and then force logout if not authorized.

Comment: There is no authenticate() function in my LoginController. It only has a middleware loading 'guest' middleware in the __constructor

Comment: So everyone is guest, and there is no login?

Comment: `class LoginController extends Controller
{
    use AuthenticatesUsers;
    protected $redirectTo = '/viewspaces';
    public function __construct()
    {

        $this->middleware('guest', ['except' => 'logout']);
    }   
}`

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
$allowed = User::join('user_types', 'user.id', '=', 'user_types.user_id')
             ->where('user.email', $email)
             ->where('user.password', $password)
             ->where('user_types.type', 'admin') // the type of user
             ->exists(); 

if($allowed) {
   if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $email, 'password' => $password])) {
      // passed
   }
   return 'not authorized';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In 5.3 you can override `authenticate()` method in the `LoginController.php`:

```
public function authenticate()
{
    if (auth()->user()->user_type !== 1) {
        auth()->logout();
    }
}
```

This code will check user type and if it's not `1` it will use [`logout()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/authentication#authenticating-users) method to sign out authenticated user.

Comment: There is no authenticate() function in my LoginController. It has a middleware loading 'guest' middleware in the __constructor